# Вопросительное предложение заканчивается невопросительным придаточным: знак?

Tags: пунктуация

> Собака, сладко свернувшись колечком, спала! Значит, всё хорошо! Или
>   это всё-таки означает совсем другое – наша животинка настолько
>   избалована и в своей жизни столько всего видела-перевидела, что
>   абсолютно уверена: и с землетрясением мы разберёмся?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, что в такой сложной конструкции трудно понять, к чему относится вопросительный знак, да и правила такие предложения не регулируют. Поэтому **лучше заменить вопросительное предложение утвердительным,** например:

Собака, сладко свернувшись колечком, спала! Значит, всё хорошо! **Хотя это может означать и совсем другое:** наша животинка настолько избалована и в своей жизни столько всего видела-перевидела, **что абсолютно уверена – с землетрясением мы тоже разберёмся.**